# File Path Struggles

Tags: python-2.7, filepath, jupyter-notebook

This is a simple question that I haven't been able to find an answer to. I want to open a csv file to read into ipython notebook to do some data analysis. How do I find out the file path when I'm trying to open(filepath, 'r') from ipython notebook. I'm not used to this because I usually just have the file in the same directory as the script that refers to it.

Thanks for any and all help,

-Sam

Answer (score 0):

The filepath can either be relative to the current working directory (where python is being run from):

```
../project/foo.csv
```

Or absolute to the filesystem:

```
/home/user/project/foo.csv
```

If you want to assign the filepath relative to the directory of your python file, you can prefix it with the file's absolute path

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../project/foo.csv')
```